# REGEX a word in a paragraph, but not a word containing that word, unless its a plural

Tags: regex

I am highlighting words in a body of text.

If I regex "Port" the word "Portuguese" is highlighted too, but I need "Ports" to be highlighted.

Any ideas? I hate regex.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
\bports?\b
```

The `?` means that the `s` character is optional. The `\b` at either end matches word-boundaries.

More generally, you could do something like this to allow words ending in `s`, `es` or `ies`:

```
\bwhatever(?:s|es|ies)?\b
```

This is very crude and you're likely to get false positives *and* negatives. If you want something more sophisticated then I suppose you'd need to look at a proper full-text search engine.

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest.

Comment: its just for text matching in an iphone application, I'm sure this will suffice. There is a finite amount of text too, so any issues I encounter will be easy to change. Thank you very much for this. :)

Answer (score 2):

The most basic answer would be this:

```
\bPort(s?)\b
```

`\b` marks beginning and ending of the word. This only matches 'Port' and 'Ports'. If you need case insensitive matching, then use something like `/i` modifier in Perl:

```
m/\bport(s?)\b/i
```

Or, if you want to match only 'port', 'Port', 'ports' and 'Ports', try

```
\b(P|p)ort(s?)\b
```